# Disable HTML escaping in Django's TextField

Tags: html, django, django-models, textfield

How can I turn off Django's automatic HTML escaping, when I write into model's TextField?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just use django's [safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter. In your template you would do something like this:

```
{{ instance.my_text_field|safe }}
```

Comment: As an alert, this allows for XSS attacks. Javascript tags can be used to input malicious code.

Comment: Right, you should be careful with this and only apply the `safe` filter to content you can trust. That's what the filter name implies ; )

Answer (score 20):

One way to do it is to put a function in your model which returns the data marked as safe:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe 

class MyModel(models.Model): 
    my_textfield = models.TextField()

    def display_my_safefield(self): 
        return mark_safe(self.my_textfield)
```

Then in the template you would have to use:

```
{{ instance.display_my_safefield }}
```

Comment: If you use django's safe filter you do not need to modify the model at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think the **better** way to do it is as @Daniel Vassallo described.

### Why?

Because this way, you can do some **security operations** on the HTML code that you want to display without escaping, particularly to protect against cross site scripting (**XSS**).

For example, you can check if `my_textfield` contains a *script* tag. 
If so, mark the instance as malicious and return an **escaped** version of `my_textfield` (the normal Django behavior).

Otherwise, use `mark_safe` to return your HTML code marked as **safe**.

Here:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe 

class MyModel(models.Model): 
    my_textfield = models.TextField()
    is_malisious = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def display_my_safefield(self):
        if '<script>' in self.my_textfield:
            self.is_malicious = True
            self.save()
            return self.my_textfield
        return mark_safe(self.my_textfield)
```

And all of this doesn't need any migrations to the database.

#### Alternative approach

I think that you can do this security operation by overriding the `save()` method of your model, and including the check and any other necessary operation against malicious content inside of it. Then, you might use @bjunix solution if you ensured that any saved content is safe.

Comment: Your snippet does not provide any security if instead of `<script>` the attacker uses e.g. `<script data-name='anything'>` instead, which would still run in all modern browsers.