# HTML not rendering in Django text field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, markdown

I am attempting to use markdown to avoid having to type HTML within my wiki form, but for some reason the form is displaying HTML code instead of the intended formatting.

My view function is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from mywiki.wiki.models import Page
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import markdown


def view_page(request, page_name):
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('create.html', {'page_name':page_name})

    content = page.content    
    return render_to_response('view.html', {'page_name':page_name, 'content':markdown.markdown(content)})
```

This is my view.html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load wikilink %}

{% block title %}{{page_name}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
        <h1>{{page_name}}</h1>
        {{content|wikify}}
        <hr/>
        <a href='/mywiki/{{page_name}}/edit/'>Edit this page?</a>

{% endblock %}
```

And this is my base.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div>
Menu: <a href='/mywiki/Start/'>Start Page</a>
</div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I do have markdown installed, and my Django version is 1.4.1 (Mac).

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080559/disable-html-escaping-in-djangos-textfield

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use Django's [safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe) so as for your Html not to be escaped.

```
{{ content|safe }}
```

Comment: can you chain filters?  `{{content|wikify|safe}}`

Comment: yeah I just went and looked at the docs and they agree with you (+1 for a more concise answer than mine :P)

Comment: lifesaver, man, had to hit a few search results until I found this

Answer (score 1):

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{content|wikify}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

maybe ...