# Python Django: Enabling tags in models.TextField()

Tags: python, html, django, tags

I'd like write my own blog in django. I'm using models.TextField() to hold notes but there is one problem: I have no idea how to enable tags inside like for example: b, img or some source code (especially source code)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: very hard to understand what you intend to do. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you mean you want to store HTML? Please edit the question to make it clear. Also elaborate on what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML not rendering in Django text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416253/html-not-rendering-in-django-text-field)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080559/disable-html-escaping-in-djangos-textfield

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to handle HTML in a Django app. Firstly, since HTML is just text, a TextField is a perfectly straight forward way to store it.

What you are having issue with is entering tags, and displaying them.

Displaying tags in a template is relatively easy. Lets say your string is:

```
<p><b>My text here</b></p>
```

If you just enter this in a django template:

```
{{ blog.text }}
```

You'll see exactly that on screen, because behind the scenes Django is trying to be helpful by escaping the text to:

```
&gt;p&lt;&gt;b&lt;My text here&gt;/b&lt;&gt;/p&lt;
```

What you want is the [`safe` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to prevent his behaviour like so:

```
{{ blog.text|safe }}
```

As for entry, the simplest way is to just enter HTML tags directly into the admin interface of your blog like that above. Entering `<p>A paragraph</p>` into the admin interface will store that *as is* into the database.

For a more user-friendly approach you need to consider a [rich text editor for Django](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/), like [CKEditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) or [TinyMCE](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)