# How to load image from backend (SQL textfield ) directly by using Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a blogging website. I know django provides argument templates like

```
{% include images.html with value=sense %}
```

The above code directly works in HTML and hence everything works. The images are stored in a backend database and connected to everystory by some logic. The user can use the names of the images and call whenever they need to use it

When I try the above code directly in the backend it doesn't work because I think once something is rendered then it doesn't rerender by django HTML

I wish to paste some form of links in the django story backend. such that when it renders in HTML automatically the page should show pics in the appropriate place. If anyone has any idea how to do this kindly let me know.

So when loading stories in the database the user can put some form of links for images in the database and while rendering all images come in a certain format as specified in the block in the blog.So there can be any number of images and the count is not longer fixed as shown in the pics below where I am trying to render a image called sense from the backend which doesn't work.. whereas it directly works in the frontend.

```
<p>{{object.story_title}}</p>
<p>{{MEDIA_ROOT}}</p>

<p>{{object.story}}</p>

{% include "blogdescription/image.html" with value=sense  %}
```

[image: HTML output]
[image: Django backend]

Thank you for your time.

with regards

Comment: At the very least you need to manually render the template that you have stored in the database field before you insert it into your page...

Comment: Is there no automatic way.. like lets say I want to put 5 images in one story and 6 images in other ... i wanted to put some link while loading it in the backend such that template renders automatically

Answer (score 1):

Let me start saying that doing exactly what you want is not possible because Jinja will compile and render `{{object.story}}` and not its content (the include). It does not seem possible to use nested Jinja syntax to load any resources, includes, extends, urls, etc.

Which explains why when you place the include in the template it works but does not inside your model field.

What seems possible is to load an HTML image with a explicit URL to the resource, lets say, the content inside your text field is:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <img src="/static/myimage.jpg" alt="Object Image">
</div>
```

Template.html ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33426218/7100120)):

```
{% block content %}
    {{obj.title}}
    <br>
    {{obj.body|safe}}
{% endblock %}
```

Alternatively, it is possible to generate a HTML file to render dynamically based on `Object.field`. Note that this solution is a heavy load on the server, for every request will generate a dynamic file to be rendered.

Obj field value:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {{obj.title}}
    <hr>
    {% include 'includes/image.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
def story(request, id):
    obj = Story.objects.get(id=id)
    f = open(f'templates/generated/dynamic_template.html', 'w+')
    f.write(obj.body)
    f.seek(0)
    return render(request, 'generated/dynamic_file.html', {'obj': obj})
```

Comment: This solution i know it is already done ...... i wanted to put lets say in one story 5 images in the backend I am using a database as u mentioned above already ... the thing is if I put a link of some sort like mentioned in the backend while rendering the image should be loaded in the frontend automatically as this is a better user interaction.....in the example you have stated the user has to create it in the template and template itself is not working from the backend..so the image count is permanently fixed

Comment: Sorry, I could not completely understand what are you trying to say. But if you want more than one image per `Story`, then another model (lets say `StoryImage`) with a [many to one relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) is necessary.

Comment: What all you said is correct but you are not answering the question. Try to read the question again I have edited it a little.

Comment: Thanks Niko for the answer. Do you have any ideas has to what can be the best solution to achieve something similar to what I have said. May be javascript? I am not good with that. But I want the interface some thing like the one as stated above which will be easy for the user to use. Using such a big HTML in the middle doesn't seem very good user interaction

Comment: Hard to think of a `best` solution. But, right away, you can generate a dynamic HTML file using your `object` field and render it. I will update the answer with an alternative.