# How do I html format my blog post in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

So I want to make a blog post with HTML formatting from the admin page directly. For example from the models.py, you see the description is a TextField. When I go to the admin page to make a blog post, I want to be able to add HTML tags to my blog. So the text field will have HTML content. While I call the blog post onto the HTML template I want it to read the description as a HTML file and not just a text field.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

Blog.description at admin page

```
<HTML>
<body>
<p>Welcome to my first blog post!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

blog.html

```
  <h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>{{ blog.description }}</p>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can make use of javascript and then create those html tags ? If I am not wrong, right now in html, it is coming as string over there or not rendering ?

Comment: yup, it's coming as a string. I don't know javascript tho :/. would that be possible?

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12416289/3523510 I think it is answered :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can render it with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe). This will disable *escaping* HTML fragments, and it will thus no longer convert `<` to `&lt;` for example:

```
<h1>{{ blog.title|safe }}</h1>
  <hr>
  <p>{{ blog.description|safe }}</p>
```

You however might want to take a look at the [**`django-ckeditor`** package [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) which offers a dedicated field, widget, etc. to enable editing the text with respect to rendering.