# Django admin converts HTML entities into their characters

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a strange problem happening with the Django Admin site, where I store fragments of html inside a text field.

[image]

Once I hit save, the field becomes this:

[image]

Which is fine -- the HTML renders correctly anyway. The real problem is when I hit save again:

[image]

All HTML entities are affected by this bug, including `&nbsp;`.

Why is this happening?

---

- OS: Amazon Linux x64
- Python: 2.6
- Django: 1.4
- Database: MySQL 5.5

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: As a string, I want my HTML entities in it to remain unmodified.

Comment: What you want to do is that if you put this `&rarr;` stays in `&rarr;` not in the right arrow?

Comment: Yes. (This is expected behaviour, isn't it?)

Comment: See this answer then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080559/disable-html-escaping-in-djangos-textfield

Comment: Your proposal is well-known, and I understand. However, this is a problem specific to [THE Django Admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/), whose source code is beyond my control post-deployment. I was asking Stack Overflow if my any part of my set-up introduces this behaviour, because this bug is not known to exist across all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Django inserts your data as `unicode` but your mysql stores it as `latin_swedish`.

If you're not using South just drop your database with `DROP DATABASE foo;`. Then re-create it using `CREATE DATABASE foo CHARACTER SET UTF8;` and run `syncdb` again.

Alternatively you can convert your existing database by doing:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

But then you would have to apply that manually for each table. Although I think it's possible to only apply it for the table you're experiencing problems with.

Make sure you back your data up before doing it.

Comment: Tried it, I think we're heading the right direction, but this does exactly the opposite as intended: now every kind of entity is converted to its character. The correct solution consists of NO HTML entity being shown as their represented characters.

Comment: Actually I think I might be dead wrong. Can you please do `SHOW TABLE STATUS` after selecting your db. What does the `Collation` row say for your tables?

Comment: [latin1_swedish_ci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769901/why-is-mysqls-default-collation-latin1-swedish-ci), possibly by default...

Comment: The db is mission critical, so we'll have to wait a bit before we try this out.  Will definitely report back if it works!

Comment: changed my answer again

Comment: Nope. Altering table collation, table engine, or both, showed no sign of removing the problem. :/

Comment: What is the collation for your tables now?

Comment: It might be an AWS bug. Amazon is investigating - more to come.