# linking outside of Django site in dev mode

Tags: python, django

I'm testing a django site on the local server: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

The sites internal links all work great, even the static links. However, when I try to link to an outside link with say `<a href="http://google.com">google</a>` as text inside a text field of my blog model it doesnt render the link correctly. That blog model is then passed through as |safe (so that the html is rendered) to the template, and the link is instead trying to append everything to the static root:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/view/http://google.com
```

Anyone know how to keep my static links working, but still have links that go outside of the site?

**EDIT:**
For example, here is a blog post that is stored in a TextField() from the admin, inside my blog app. The blog post has some links. The link to the `/static/mytextfile` works fine as it appends that to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. However, the github link isnt working as it attempts to append the github link to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and thus the outputted html creates `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/http://github.com/"`:

```
<p><b>The Code</b><br>
<a href=”http://github.com/”>GitHub</a>

<p><b>Example Outputs</b>
<br><a href="/static/mytextfile.txt">a text file</a>
```

Here's the 404 error that I get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/view/%E2%80%9Dhttp://github.com/%E2%80%9D
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is how I have been 'escaping' the html filter. Up until now it has worked fine at leaving my `<p>` etc alone. It is not however leaving my `href` links alone!

```
{% autoescape off %}
{% block content %}
    <p>{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
{% endblock %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code here - I suspect your description of the problem is not accurate, since your example uses http and https for the Google URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong with your double quote characters for the GitHub link.

Instead of:

```
<p><b>The Code</b><br>
<a href=”http://github.com/”>GitHub</a>
```

Try:

```
<p><b>The Code</b><br>
<a href="http://github.com/">GitHub</a>
```

Comment: okay you are definitely on the right track! That 404 error I was getting was showing %E2%80%9D which I guess are those weird quotes. I went back in to edit the quotes. They look normal now in the TextField(), but when I view the blog post and inspect the element it's rendering:
 <a href="" http:="" www.github.com="" ''="">github</a>
which is definitely not what I typed in. My other HTML is rendering just fine, any idea why the links are throwing me off?

Comment: This is what I do to normally escape the HTML, but for some reason the <a href= tag isnt escaping properly.

Comment: How exactly do you escape the HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080559/disable-html-escaping-in-djangos-textfield

Comment: I finally got it. The quotes werent "the right kind" of double quotes as you pointed out. as soon as I fixed that and added in http:// prefixes it realized that I wasnt looking for relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>`.