# TinyMCE shows HTML tags, inline CSS codes after saving data

Tags: python, html, django, tinymce, text-editor

So, I am using TinyMCE as a text editor in my Django application. It shows all HTML tags and inline CSS codes after saving and reloading data. I've used also `'encoding':'xml'`, then I am getting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bIiz.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Django framework is likely escaping the content as a safety precaution.  It would appear there is an easy way to stop it from doing that:

[Disable HTML escaping in Django's TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080559/disable-html-escaping-in-djangos-textfield)

Comment: I am using that text-editor in my admin form. I didn't understand, where to write this filter ? ```{{ instance.my_text_field|safe }}```

Comment: help me. You know, there is no template of default admin form @Michael Fromin

Comment: I have never used Django so I can't really tell you how to do that.  Sorry.

Comment: Verify that the value in your database field looks like normal html. If it does, you need to add the `safe` filter to the template that renders your linked screenshot. You shouldn't need to change anything in the django admin.